# How are different branches stored locally from git on my disk?

Tags: git, github, version-control

I have only one version repository sitting on my local HDD but multiple branches on Github. Shouldn't there be copies of code per branch? what version of code do I have sitting on my local disk?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Shouldn't there be copies of code per branch?

No.  This is not how Git's branch names work.

What Git stores is not, in a sense, branches at all.  Git stores *commits*.  Commits are nearly everything in Git.  Where branches come in is much later, where they have a rather minor role.  They're important to *humans*, of course, because the actual name of any commit is a big ugly hash ID that is useless to humans.  Branch names let us use names instead of hash IDs.  But Git mostly really cares about the commits, with their hash IDs.

> I have only one version repository sitting on my local HDD but multiple branches on Github.

Generally, the repository on your local drive is a *clone* of the repository on GitHub.  Or, we could equally say that the repository on GitHub is a clone of the repository on your local drive.  Neither repository is "better" than the other, they just have different computers to hold them, and possibly slightly different sets of commits, and more-likely different branch *names* in them (but since Git cares more about the *commits*, that doesn't matter so much to Git).

To understand how this works, start with the commit.  Each commit—named by some big ugly hash ID, such as [`8a0ba68f6dab2c8b1f297a0d46b710bb9af3237a`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8a0ba68f6dab2c8b1f297a0d46b710bb9af3237a)—stores a complete snapshot of some set of files.  Along with that snapshot, each commit has some *metadata*, some data about the commit.  If you made the commit yourself, for instance, the commit stores your name and email address, and the time-stamp for *when* you made the commit.  And, each commit generally stores the hash ID of its previous or *parent* commit.  (The parent of `8a0ba68f6dab2c8b1f297a0d46b710bb9af3237a` above is `15cc2da0b5aaf5350f180951450e0a5318f7d34d`, for instance.)

Git uses these *parent* links to find commits.  Let's consider a tiny repository that you created recently, in which you have made just three commits.  Each commit has some big ugly hash ID, but let's use single uppercase letters instead.  The first commit you ever made is therefore commit `A`.  Because it *is* the first commit, it has *no* parent.

Then, with commit `A` made, you made commit `B`.  It has `A` as its parent.  Likewise, you used `C` to make `B`, so `C` stores `B`'s hash ID.

Whenever we have the hash ID of some commit, we say that we can *point to* that commit.  So `C` points to `B`, and `B` points to `A`.  If we draw this, we get:

```
A <-B <-C
```

Now, with simple single uppercase letters and this drawing, it's obvious that we need to *start* at `C` and work backwards.  This is what Git does, but the *way* that Git finds commit `C` is to use a *branch name*.  Since we just started this repository we probably are still using `master`, so let's draw that in:

```
A <-B <-C   <--master
```

The name `master` holds the hash ID of commit `C`, so that Git can find `C`.  From there, Git can work backwards, to `B` and then `A`.

If we want to add a *new* commit, we run `git checkout master`, which gets us a copy of `C` that we can work on, and remembers that we're now on `master` which is commit `C`.  We do our work, `git add` files as needed, and run `git commit`.  Git makes a new commit `D` (from whatever is in the *index*, which I'm not going to define here), and sets `D` to point back to `C`:

```
A--B--C   <--master
       \
        D
```

Now the tricky part happens: since we just created `D`, and we're on `master`, Git now *updates* `master` with whatever the real hash ID is for new commit `D`.  So now `master` points to `D`, not `C`:

```
A--B--C
       \
        D   <--master
```

and we can straighten out the kink in the drawing (and I like to loosen up the arrow a bit too):

```
A--B--C--D   <-- master
```

Now suppose we decide to add a *new branch*.  We run, e.g., `git checkout -b develop`.  What this does is just add a new *name*, but keep all the same *commits*.  The new name, `develop`, points to the commit we choose, which defaults to the one we're using right now, i.e., commit `D`:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- master, develop
```

Now we need a way to draw which *branch name* we're using.  To do this we'll attach the word `HEAD` (in all uppercase) to one of the two branches.  Since we did `git checkout` to attach `HEAD` to the new `develop`, let's draw that:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- master, develop (HEAD)
```

Now it's time to make another new commit.  Without doing anything else, we modify some files, use `git add` to copy the updated files into the index, and run `git commit` to make a new commit, which we'll call `E` (but which gets, as usual, some incomprehensible hash ID).  When Git updates a branch *name*, the name it updates is the one that has `HEAD` attached to it, so the graph now looks like this:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- master
          \
           E   <-- develop (HEAD)
```

At this point, suppose I clone your repository (directly from your machine, or from an exact copy you send to GitHub, with the same commits and same branch names).  My Git will at first do this:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- origin/master
          \
           E   <-- origin/develop
```

Here, I don't have *any* branches.  I have all the same *commits*, but what is remembering their ends is not *branch names*, but rather *remote-tracking names*.  Instead of `master`, I have `origin/master` to remember commit `D`'s hash ID.  Instead of `develop`, I have `origin/develop` to remember `E`'s hash ID.

As the last step of my clone, my own Git tries to `git checkout master`.  Instead of failing because I don't *have* a `master`, this actually *creates* my `master`, using my `origin/master` that my Git copied from your Git's `master`.  So now I have:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- origin/master, master (HEAD)
          \
           E   <-- origin/develop
```

If I now run `git checkout develop`, my Git will look through my repository and will not find a `develop`, but it *will* find an `origin/develop`.  My Git will then *create* a new *name*, `develop`, pointing to commit `E`, and attach `HEAD` to that name instead of to `master`:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- origin/master, master
          \
           E   <-- origin/develop, develop (HEAD)
```

Note that *no commits have been copied*.  Git merely added a new *name*, pointing to some existing commit.  The existing commit was already there, in my local repository.

#### You connect two Git repositories with `fetch` and `push`

This is how you get updates from the GitHub repository.  If they have some new commit(s) that you don't have, you can run `git fetch` in your Git repository.  Your Git uses the `origin` name, which your Git created during your original `git clone` operation, to find the URL for GitHub.  Your Git then calls up GitHub and your Git and their Git have a little conversation.

With `git fetch`, your Git asks their Git about their branch names and the final commits on each of those names.  Their Git might say: *my `master` points to some commit with big ugly hash*—let's just call this `H`, rather than trying to guess the actual hash ID.  Your Git looks at your repository and says to itself: *I don't have `H`, I'd better ask for it.*  Your Git asks their Git about `H`; they say `H`'s parent is `G`, whose parent is `F`, whose parent is `D`.  You both have `D`, so this part of the conversation is done.  Their Git might also say: *my `develop` points to commit `E`.*  Your Git already has `E`, so this part of the conversation is done too.  There are no other names left to worry about, so now your Git has their Git send over commits `F`, `G`, and `H`, which your Git saves away in your repository:

```
           F--G--H   <-- origin/master
          /
A--B--C--D   <-- master
          \
           E   <-- origin/develop, develop (HEAD)
```

Note that aside from adding *new* commits to your own repository, the only other thing your Git has done is update all your `origin/*` names so that they match the other Git's names.  That is, your `origin/master` has moved from the shared commit `D` to the now-shared commit `H`.

#### Fetch is always safe, but `git push` is different

It's always safe to run `git fetch`: this connects your Git to some other Git, gets any *new* commits from them, and updates your *remote-tracking names*.  Since those names are just remembering *their* work, not *your* work, that's safe.  If you have made new commits, your new commits are still on *your* branches, which are not *their* branches, other than whatever commits you both have in common.

When you use `git push`, your Git calls up their Git and the two Gits have a very similar conversation.  Your Git offers their Git some new commits, if you have new ones.  But then, instead of your Git updating your *remote-tracking* names, your Git offers their Git a polite request: *Please, if it's OK, update your `master` to match my `master`,* or *please, if it's OK, update your `develop` to match my `develop`*—or perhaps even both.  (You can push as many branch names as you like in one go.)

Suppose that after the earlier `git fetch`, you had this:

```
           F--G--H   <-- origin/master
          /
A--B--C--D   <-- master
          \
           E   <-- origin/develop, develop (HEAD)
```

You stayed on your `develop` and made some new commits, which we'll call `I` and `J`, so now you have this:

```
           F--G--H   <-- origin/master
          /
A--B--C--D   <-- master
          \
           E   <-- origin/develop
            \
             I--J   <-- develop (HEAD)
```

But, unbeknownst to you, someone *else* added a new commit to *their* `develop`.  That commit has a hash ID that you don't have anywhere.  Let's call it `K` in *their* Git, so that *they* have this:

```
           F--G--H   <-- master
          /
A--B--C--D
          \
           E--K   <-- develop
```

You send them `I` and `J`, so that now they have this:

```
           F--G--H   <-- master
          /
A--B--C--D
          \
           E--K   <-- develop
            \
             I--J   <-- (polite request to make develop go here)
```

If they were to accept your request, and *move* their `develop`, what happens to their commit `K`?  They end up with this:

```
           F--G--H   <-- master
          /
A--B--C--D
          \
           E--K   ???
            \
             I--J   <-- develop
```

As we described above, the way Git works with commits and branch names is that it uses the branch name to find the *last* commit, and then works backwards.  Working backwards from `J`, their Git would go to `J`.  From `J` they would go back to `I`, then `E`, then `D`, `C`, `B`, and `A`.  What this means is that commit `K` is *lost!*

As a result, their Git will say *no* to your polite request: *No, if I moved my `develop`, I would lose some commit(s).*  (Your Git reports this as "rejected" and "not a fast-forward".)

In this case, what you need to do is to `git fetch` to pick up *their* new commit `K`, then do something in your own repository to accommodate it.  That's for another set of questions, though (all of which are already answered on StackOverflow).

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: `git` stores all branches, tags, commits and notes in a single repository. It can also display combined views of multiple repositories (e.g. local and remote) and `fetch` and `push` stuff between repositories. Each branch points to some specific commit in the repository and each commit points to zero or more parent commits. The normal files (that is, everything but the stuff in the subdirectory `.git`) you see are called workspace or working tree and you can display the status of your workspace by calling `git status`. To see list of all currently known branches (both local and remote) you can use `git branch --all`. To select which files you have in your workspace, use `git checkout`.

Long answer: see the answer by @torek and read https://jwiegley.github.io/git-from-the-bottom-up/

Answer (score 0):

Run `git branch` to list the branches you have locally and the current branch you are on. If you want to pull remote branches locally, run `git fetch <origin> <branch name>`